# Multiply in Groovy SoapUI

Tags: soapui, web-service, groovy

I would like to multiply the below response by 100, then compare it with the request. How do I multiply using Groovy? This is for SoapUI.

```
def response = context.expand( '${abcd#Response#$[16][\'XXXXXXX\']}' )
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question please. I'm not sure what you want multiplying.

Comment: Some Queries from your question-- 1. Are you want to multiply your response with 100? 2. is your response integer value or String? 3. What is the Request, want to compare it ? Please put comment for these queries.